# В IE7 не отображается часть страницы

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

В ИЕ7 не отображается верхняя часть [страницы](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index6/index.html) (там должны быть меню, поиск, слайдер). Не могу разобраться, почему она пропадает, помогите разобраться.

Comment: Все отображается, есть только кидающийся в глаза минус - не адаптивный сайт. Пришлось даже горизонтально скроллить.

Comment: я в ие7 вижу такое http://i.imgur.com/8jLEQ.jpg . а что значит "не адаптивный сайт" в случае конкретно этой страницы?

Comment: Вот что я назвал не адаптивным и не удобным http://s51.radikal.ru/i133/1212/15/748cf48db33d.jpg
Адаптивный сайт - гугл подскажет.
К сожалению нет IE7, в остальных ИЕ нормально отображается.
Код у сайта нагроможденный, куча файлов сss, сброс стилей, еще советую если используете хтмл5шив то переделайте сайт под 5хтмл.
А вообще лучше стереть то что там есть и поставить цмс типо вордпресса или написать сайт самому следуя к примеру этому http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml

Comment: ну я вообще-то про ие7 конкретно спрашиваю, это указано и в заголовке вопроса и в теле поста, зачем тогда отвечать, если его у вас нет. про адаптивный сайт спасибо, почитаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите у header position:relative.

Comment: спасибо, помогло)